# cube.js: subquery in FROM clause

Tags: cube.js

How to do a subquery in the FROM clause in cube.js. There is only one table.

```
SELECT col_a FROM 
       (SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table_name WHERE col_c=some_val ORDER BY time DESC) 
WHERE col_b=some_other_value
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the same Table you could define a cube.js segment in your schema then specify the segment you are querying in your JSON Query. Refer [this page](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/reference/segments) to  in the Docs.